# New to JavaScript and need help on my first program

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to add a function to my website so when the user clicks on a footnote the browser will display it inline. Here is how far I have gotten,

```
var locate= document.getElementById("footnote1");
var note= document.getElementById("footnotes2");
function footnote() {
    locate.onclick= note.style.display="inline";
};
```

any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Adding a larger portion of the source code for your page might be helpful.

Comment: go to jsfiddle.net and setup your html and share it with us. Also, if you could explain what the end result has to look like. Got before and after images? Just saying "footnote to appear inline" doesn't make sense and if you aren't comfortable with css/javascript it may not mean what you want it to.

Comment: no need this was enough code to work with...

Comment: As Kotsu suggested, try to give us a sample of the HTML you have so far, as well as the Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9H7H/4/) of what you want.

```
var locate = document.getElementById("footnote1");
var note = document.getElementById("footnotes2");
locate.onclick = function() {
    note.style.display = "inline";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/v8fHE/

you just had to wrap the onclick action in a function

```
trigger.onclick=function(){toChange.style.background="#FF0000"};
```